# Doctrine Relations Problem

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I am trying to run this query:

```
   $record = Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('m.*')
                        ->from('Modification m')
                        ->leftJoin('m.Location l')
                        ->leftJoin('l.Site s')
                        ->where('CONCAT(s.baseUrl, s.modUrlPrefix, l.urlSuffix) = ?', (string)$url)
                        ->fetchOne();
```

However, it fails with the error

> Doctrine_Table_Exception: Unknown relation alias Location

The relationships in the yaml file looks like this (Two one to many relationships. Both Modification and Site have many Locations):

```
Site:
    columns:
        id:
            type: integer
            primary: true
            autoincrement: true

Modification:
    columns:
        id:
            type: integer
            primary: true
            autoincrement: true

Location:
    columns:
        modification_id: integer
        site_id: integer
    relations:
        Modification:
            foreignAlias: Locations
        Site:
            foreignAlias: Locations
        Category:
            foreignAlias: Locations
```

What am I not putting in the yaml file that I need to? As far as I can make out, I have setup the yaml file the same as the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's m.Locations no? 
your yaml specifie this alias, not Location

```
Modification:
        foreignAlias: Locations
```

i never read the yaml file, so I'm not sure

Comment: You know the questions that I always feel very stupid after asking them? This is one of them. I can't believe I missed something so obvious. Many thanks.